# Custom Model Binder Which Will Only Work In One Area of MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding, custom-model-binder

I've used custom model binders which are configured in the Global.asax file. Is it possible to only use this model binder under certain areas of the application?

```
public class CreatorModelBinder : IModelBinder
{

    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        //what logic can i put here so that this only happens when the controller is in certain area- and when it's not in that area- then the default model binding would work
        var service = new MyService();
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null && service.IsLoggedIn)
            return service.Creator;
        return new Creator {};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to invoke the default model binder you should derive from `DefaultModelBinder` instead of directly implementing the `IModelBinder` interface.

And then:

```
public class CreatorModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var area = controllerContext.RouteData.Values["area"] as string;
        if (string.Equals(area, "Admin"))
        {
            // we are in the Admin area => do custom stuff
            return someCustomObject;
        }

        // we are not in the Admin area => invoke the default model binder
        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the following logic:

```
if(controllerContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"].ToString()=="yourArea")
        {
            //do something
        }
```